# Cygwin to display cpu usage of a process?

Tags: windows, cygwin

Hopefully, this question can be resolved, as I've been searching all over the web for answers to no avail. Does Cygwin have a command to display cpu % of a Windows process? I know that the command `top` can display this information, but it only displays Cygwin processes and not Windows. There's another command, `ps`, but this doesn't display cpu %. Perhaps there's a command that has the best of both `top` and `ps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't need "native" Cygwin application to do that, because Cygwin can execute also native Windows' executables. In fact, Cygwin's "native" executables **are** Windows' native executables. They just use Cygwin's DLLs to map Linux system calls to Windows' ones.

Just use for example package [PsTools from SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) (now part of Microsoft). It contains **pslist** which is able to output running Windows' processes information.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in cygwin, to check if any audio is playing:

t1=`/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/tasklist /fi "ImageName eq audiodg.exe" /v /nh`

(remove the "/nh" to see column headers)

(Actually, this only returned the total cpu usage. But i put it in a loop in a script w/ 'date +%s to get the time, and then calculated the percentage.)