# How can I get the cpu% usage of a Windows Pid on the command line?

Tags: java, windows, cpu, pid

I am aware of many ways of getting this by process name but I have many processes with identical names (Java) so need to use the PID.

Happy to use any tool/language that would get this done.

Ultimately this would be called using Cygwin.
Thanks

Comment: Please post you code

Comment: I think this post have answer to your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292737/cygwin-to-display-cpu-usage-of-a-process

Comment: Thanks but I don't believe PsTools gives you a CPU % value for a process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VB Script seems to do the trick, passing the pid on the command line:
(initial for loop could be omitted)

```
For Each Process in GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where Handle =  " & WScript.Arguments.Item(0) &  "")
 WScript.echo Process.Handle & " " & Process.name & " " & CPUUSage(Process.Handle) & " %"   
Next

Function CPUUSage( ProcID )
  On Error Resume Next

Set objService = GetObject("Winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!\Root\Cimv2")

For Each objInstance1 in objService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process where IDProcess = '" & ProcID & "'")
    N1 = objInstance1.PercentProcessorTime
    D1 = objInstance1.TimeStamp_Sys100NS
    Exit For
Next

 WScript.Sleep(2000)

For Each perf_instance2 in objService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process where IDProcess = '" & ProcID & "'")
    N2 = perf_instance2.PercentProcessorTime
    D2 = perf_instance2.TimeStamp_Sys100NS
    Exit For
Next

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", _
                                      wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each objItem In colItems
    Nc = objItem.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
Next

' CounterType - PERF_100NSEC_TIMER_INV
' Formula - (1- ((N2 - N1) / (D2 - D1))) x 100
Nd = (N2 - N1)
Dd = (D2 - D1)
' Nd/Dd = number of cores used.
' ((Nd/Dd)/Nc) * 100 = % of whole box used
PercentProcessorTime = ((Nd/Dd)/Nc)*100

CPUUSage = Round(PercentProcessorTime ,2)
End Function
```

For instance (in cygwin) if the above is in file cpu.vbs:
cmd /c cscript /nologo cpu.vbs 64940

Answer (score 0):

You could use a quick powershell script:

```
$searchPid = 6204
get-process | where-object Id -eq $searchPid | select-object CPU
```

At the command line, you should just need this:

```
powershell "get-process | where-object Id -eq 6204 | select-object CPU"
```

**UPDATE**

As noted in comments, get-process returns only the CPU time the process has used in seconds, so it doesn't help with percentage of usage of the CPU. Looks like a WMI call should get that percentage for you:

```
powershell "get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where-object idprocess -eq 6204 | select PercentProcessorTime"
```

Comment: Thanks - that gives a value under the CPU heading - what does that represent? 
The Java process I'm looking at is idle and the value the above script gave was 1123.328...

Comment: Good call - I had used the cmdlet before for other purposes, but didn't realize that wasn't CPU percentage. Per TechNet - "The amount of processor time that the process has used on all processors, in seconds.", so let me find a better cmdlet/call to use. sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks - is that % of 1 core or all cores?
I'm not sure this value is correct - I have a running process that is using  40+% according to Task Manager but the above command appears to be pegged at 100

Comment: I believe that's total of all cores, but you can check by running this and see if results of non "_total" entries add up to either 100 or 100 * (# of cores)

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by non "_total" entries

Comment: When i ran the command on my machine, I saw a list of actual processes running totaling 100 as well as a "_Total" item in the list that was also 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below command with psTools

```
pslist <pid> -s
```

Comment: That gives a CPU Time and Elapsed Time, not cpu %